# how to correctly call the error_log to display the value in Controller when option is called from View

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, model-view-controller

I am trying to log the values in my controller-> action.php. These values are being `POST`-ed from the view -> a form with a list of fields. In my form, I have a created a `<select>` box with a list of options and each options have details that are associated with it.

For e.g ->in my dropdown list of option A, I have the following details that are associated: Name, regNum and address. option B has the following details of Name, regNum and address as well. Each of this details that are associated are unique.

Hence, when I submit my form, the details that are associated with with each option will be `POST`-ed to the controller code. Hence to ensure that the correct values are `POST`-ed to the controller, *.php, I have hence created an error log file in the controller, *.php as following:

```
 <?php

 if ( (isset($_POST)) && (0 < count($_POST)) )
{

//error log for details associated with option A
error_log(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."_-ipad,agencyName: ".$_POST['agencyName']."\n",3,"/var/tmp/*/post.log");
error_log(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."_-ipad, agencyRegistrationNum: ".$_POST['agentRegistrationNum']."\n",3,"/var/tmp/*/post.log");
error_log(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."_-ipad, agencyAddress: ".$_POST['agentAddress']."\n",3,"/var/tmp/*/post.log");
} 
//error log for details associated with option B
error_log(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."_-ipad,agencyName: ".$_POST['agency2Name']."\n",3,"/var/tmp/*/post.log");
error_log(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."_-ipad, agencyRegistrationNum: ".$_POST['agent2RegistrationNum']."\n",3,"/var/tmp/*/post.log");
error_log(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."_-ipad, agencyAddress: ".$_POST['agent2Address']."\n",3,"/var/tmp/*/post.log");
}        
 ....

}
.....
?>
```

Furthermore, there are multiple error_log to monitor each individual details for each individual option

And this is the code that displays the details for each individual  options in the View [form] (**I deliberately didn't insert the `<select>` code as it is not part of the question**):

```
function val(ddbox) {

    if ( ddbox.options[ddbox.selectedIndex].value == "Others"){
            document.getElementById("extradiv").style.display = "block";
    }else{
            document.getElementById("extradiv").style.display = "none";
    }
     if( ddbox.options[ddbox.selectedIndex].value != "Others"){
            document.getElementById("Agency1").style.display = "block";
    }else{
            document.getElementById("Agency1").style.display = "none";
    }
}


<form name="*" id="*" method="POST" action="*.php" onsubmit="return checkForm(this)">

<div id = "Others" style ="display:none">

                    <li class="bigfield"><input placeholder="Agency Name" type="text" name="agencyOthersName" id="agencyOthersName"/></li>
                <li class="bigfield"><input placeholder="Agency Registration Num" type="text" name="agentOthersRegistrationNum" id="agentOthersRegistrationNum"/></li>
                <li class="bigfield"><input placeholder="Agency Address" type="text" name="agentOthersAddress" id="agentOthersAddress"/></li>

                 </div>

                 <!-- when user select other options-->
                <div  id = "Agency1" style ="display:none" >

               <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Name A" type="text" name="agencyName" id="agencyName" readonly></li>
                <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Registration Num A" type="text" name="agentRegistrationNum" id="agentRegistrationNum" readonly/></li>
                <li class="bigfield"><input value="Agency Address A" type="text" name="agentAddress" id="agentAddress" readonly/></li>

                 </div>
</form>
```

Hence, the issue is that when I submit the form and when the error_log is displayed, it will display the redundant log as well as the correct log.

for e.g-> when I select option B from the select list in the form, the details of option B will be pulled and displayed, hence when I submit the form, the error log is only suppose to display the details of option B and not also display the details of option A and option C. In summary, it is displaying all the details.

Hence, how am I able to correctly call the error log in the controller to display the details when the option in View (form)is being selected

Comment: Show you current code that attempts to load the error log data

Comment: @RiggsFolly, what do you mean? I am just using the error_log to capture the value from the form.

Comment: Ok then I dont understand the question, please try to expand on _Hence, how am I able to correctly call the error log in the controller to display the details when the option in View (form)is being selected_

Comment: @RiggsFolly my error_log is in the controller code to capture values that are associated with the select list in the form, view code. so rightfully, when I select optionB, the error log in the controller code that is monitoring  the values for option B should be displayed only. However at this point in time, when I select option B, the error log that is monitoring the values for option A and option C and option D are showing as well besides option B. Hence, I just need to change the error_log such that it will only display according to the option selected in the form. hope i made it clear

Answer (score 0):

Some questions to ask yourself:

- What do you send via POST, when submitting the form?
- What do you accept, when the POST is incoming?
- Where is the decision based on the incoming POST data to do/display something?

For me, it looks like your are changing only the visibility of form elements, but are not reducing the actual form data send to the server to only the selected element. In other words: do not only change the visibility to hidden/none, but send only the values of the selected/active form element.

Or: send everything via POST and reduce the incoming POST array. Your POST array will for instance contain empty elements (from the hidden selects) and you might simply drop them. In the end you will know which data was send.

Then check your $_POST array and decide what to do based on the incoming form labels and values.

In the end it boils down to wrapping the error_log() calls into condition checks. Just using pseudocode to explain it...

```
if( you have a value for $_POST['agentName1'])) { 
  // then select 1 was send and you only need to log the errors for 1
  error_log(... stuff for 1 ...);
}

if(you have a value for $_POST['agentName2'])) {
  // then select 2 was send and you only need to log the errors for 2
  error_log(... stuff for 2 ...);
}
```

Comment: True, I have contemplated of using the conditional checks to limit the visibility of the error log. To note that I have approached it in this manner ` if($_POST['agency1Name'] != ""){..show error log}`,  however, I have also realised that there will always be value for each agent as there are already details associated to each option

Comment: Ok, that means you can not decide based on the value and the select itself gets into the focus. You could figure out what was selected and add a hidden form element, which is send to the server, too. Boils down to: How can i send the data of only one select tag, when i have multiple select tags in a form, right?

Comment: Yes!!May I ask how do you that??I am racking my brains out . I have edited the current code

Comment: I've played around with jquery and came up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/AY7bV/3/ Are we getting closer to a solution? What do you think? When you press send the value is logged to the console (F12 in the browser). At that point you could probably switch from native HTML posting to the PHP endpoint to using jQuery for an Ajax POST. It depends.

Comment: I think this is brilliant. Sorry about yesterday, was too tired to actually continue. However, I would like to further ask you: I would like to improve on what I have done, how could I incorporate your javascript, the code line starting from: javascript code line 10 into what I have done. Furthermore, I have observed that you have  3 different <div> tags in your html,however, at this point in time, I am actually planning of using just 1 <div> tag for the 3 different "Group" while another <div> tag is an input text field for "Others". Reason is that, I will use that to ref the dB in the future.

Comment: I hope you understand what I am trying to say.